# Azure Storage Blob file download and Upload via APIM

Tags: azure-storage, azure-api-management

I have a Azure Storage account. I have added an API in APIM which will call a Storage account SAS URL to download the file. The download works fine except that it takes too much time to download. Say 5 mins for 80 mb file.

APIM is Developer tier.
APIM and Storage account reside in the same region.
Storage account is LRS.

Is it because of APIM Developer tier as it does now provide an SLA.

Note: The Blob sas url take just 30 to 40 sec max. But via APIM it takes 5 mins.

Update1: I tried two instances of APIM, one with developer tier and other with Consumpltion tier. I could see the download of the file is quite fast with consumption tier compared with developer tier.

Comment: Any particular policies you have configured in APIM?

Answer (score -1):

Please check with any  policy that you configured  in APIM
Like  **bandwidth limit or download limit policy** in APIM.

For more about the azure APIM policy refer this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies):

For more details refer this [document](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03880b1f-9b8d-4a78-a4c1-1824920ca6bc/azure-blob-file-download-through-azure-api-management-fails-with-error-backendconnectionfailure?forum=azureapimgmt):

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer - you're referring the OP to some documentation and giving a suggestion to check. You don't know if this is the issue. But also: this question isn't related to programming and is off-topic here (and should be closed, accordingly, and moved to a different stack exchange site)